# About release of react-native@0.50.x, version mismatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-app, expo, babel-jest

I'm react-native app developer and recently tried to code react-native web and mobile app from same code base.

Here's [a link](https://sparkyspace.com/write-once-run-anywhere-with-create-react-native-app-and-react-native-web/)! I've tried that.

But I have a problem while following those instructions.

I have tried 3 whole days until yesterday but didn’t find out proper versions of react-native, react, jest-expo, expo and react-native-web.
i.e. react-native@0.48.4 required react@16.0.0-alpha.12. but  jest-expo requires react@16.0.0-beta.5

I’ve tried almost all of versions, but didn’t find and figure out that before release of react-native@0.50.x , it’s impossible to use that article.

Could you help me?

Comment: Enhanced the title to make the question clearer.